# Ошибка: отсутствует определение процедуры

Tags: pascal

Почему при компиляции возникает ошибка: отсутствует определение процедуры prov?

```
unit proverka;
interface
procedure prov(c, y, z: integer);
implementation
procedure prov;
var c, y, z: integer;
begin
 if c>0 then c:=c
  else WriteLn('Ошибка');
  if y>0 then y:=y
  else WriteLn('Ошибка');
  if y<=1497*8 then y:=y
  else WriteLn('Ошибка');
  if z>0 then z:=z
  else WriteLn('Ошибка');
  if z<=100*1024*1024 then z:=z
  else WriteLn('Ошибка');
end;
end.
```

Comment: @3a9, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильный код:

```
unit proverka;
interface
procedure prov(var c, y, z: integer);
implementation
procedure prov(var c, y, z: integer);
begin
 if c>0 then c:=c
  else WriteLn('Ошибка');
  if y>0 then y:=y
  else WriteLn('Ошибка');
  if y<=1497*8 then y:=y
  else WriteLn('Ошибка');
  if z>0 then z:=z
  else WriteLn('Ошибка');
  if z<=100*1024*1024 then z:=z
  else WriteLn('Ошибка');
end;
end.
```

Comment: почему в unit нельзя использовать ShowMessage на него он ругается ?

Comment: @3a9 в какой секции модуля?

Comment: вместо WriteLn

Comment: @3a9 Вы же пишете на Паскале? В нём нет этой процедуры, она только в Дельфи.

Comment: Pascal ABС. В отдельном от модуля файле я пишу ShowMessage и все нормально работает. Ладно, таким способом обойдусь, спасибо еще раз =)